# cannot open popup window using web.sitemap

Tags: asp.net

I am using following node in my web.sitemap.

When I click, the page has to go to url `~/BA/Rep/Administrator/Default.aspx` and also have to open a pop up `/BA/Rep/Administrator/Authorization.aspx` at same time.

so far I can only go to url but cannot open  pop up. how do I achieve this?

```
<siteMapNode url="~/BA/Rep/Administrator/Default.aspx" pop_up="/BA/Rep/Administrator/Authorization.aspx"  title="Authorization" ></siteMapNode>
```

Answer (score 0):

[siteMapNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapnode_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) does not contain an attribute called `pop_up`.

Presumably you would need to add some `javascript` to your /administrator/default.aspx page which performed a `window.open` when the page was loaded.